# Checking on a property of a collection of case-class instances

Tags: scala

Consider a simple case-class "card" with two properties ("number" and "color") like this:

```scala
case class Card(number: Int, color: String)
```

Consider a sequence of cards like this one:

```scala
val cards = Seq(
  Card(5, "red"),
  Card(7, "red"),
  Card(3, "black"))
```

Now suppose I wanted to solve these problems in a Scala-idiomatic way (functionally oriented?):

- Find if all the cards have the same color
- Find if all the cards have the same number
- Find if the cards are in ascending order

Concretely, I would have to implement these functions:

```scala
// Do the cards all have the same color?
def haveSameColor(cards: Seq[Card], ifEmpty: Boolean = true): Boolean = {
  ???
}

// Do the cards all have the same number?
def haveSameNumber(cards: Seq[Card], ifEmpty: Boolean = true): Boolean = {
  ???
}

// Are cards ordered ascendingly?
def areAscending(cards: Seq[Card], ifEmpty: Boolean = true): Boolean = {
  ???
}
```

What would be possible / best approaches? Looping, recursing, folding, reducing?

Comment: Do you really need custom behaviour in case of emptiness?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: is it clear what the default answer should be in case of emptiness? It is not for me. I thought I would make it optional before people started asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forall` short-quits as soon as it met first false

```
def haveSameColor(cards: Seq[Card], ifEmpty: Boolean = true) = {
  if (cards.isEmpty)  ifEmpty 
  else cards.forall(x => x.color.equals(cards.head.color))
}

// not much different approach
def haveSameNumber(cards: Seq[Card], ifEmpty: Boolean = true): Boolean = {
  if (cards.isEmpty)  ifEmpty 
  else cards.forall(x => x.number == cards.head.number)
}

def areAscending(cards: Seq[Card], ifEmpty: Boolean = true): Boolean = {
  if (cards.isEmpty)  ifEmpty
  else cards.zip(cards.tail).forall{ case (prev, next) => prev.number <= next.number}
}
```

Although, you said

> is it clear what the default answer should be in case of emptiness? It is not for me.

As you can see there is a lot of repetition in function -- a clear sign there is something wrong -- I would go with functions without ifEmpty parameter.

Comment: I guess this is also an interesting "philosophical" question: whose responsibility is it when having a function that operates only on non-empty sequences? For the caller to check and not-call (or be punished with a runtime error), or for the implementer by handling the (corner) case?

Comment: In the Scala collections, `head` throws an exception when called on an empty collection, while `headOption` returns `None`.  In both cases the callee handles the corner case.

Comment: you were answering me or Sebastian?)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
case class Card(number: Int, color: String)

def haveSameColor(cards: Seq[Card]): Boolean = {
  cards.groupBy{_.color}.size == 1
}

def haveSameNumber(cards: Seq[Card]): Boolean = {
  cards.groupBy{_.number}.size == 1
}

def areAscending(cards: Seq[Card]): Boolean = {
  cards.view.zip(cards.drop(1)).forall(c => c._1.number <= c._2.number)
}
```

and so for

```
val cards = Seq(
  Card(5, "red"),
  Card(7, "red"),
  Card(3, "black"))
```

we have

```
haveSameColor(cards)
false

haveSameNumber(cards)
false

areAscending(cards)
false
```

Moreover, embed those methods in an implicit class, as follows,

```
implicit class RichCardsChecking(val cards: Seq[Card]) extends AnyVal {
    def haveSameColor(): Boolean = {
      cards.groupBy{_.color}.size == 1
    }

    def haveSameNumber(): Boolean = {
      cards.groupBy{_.number}.size == 1
    }

    def areAscending(): Boolean = {
      cards.view.zip(cards.tail).forall(c => c._1.number <= c._2.number)
    }
}
```

and thus

```
cards.haveSameColor()
false

cards.haveSameNumber()
false

cards.areAscending()
false
```

Comment: cards.drop(1) === cards.tail

Comment: Why `cards.view`? What does it do?

Comment: @Sebastian-N: view turns the collection lazy, thus for each element it zips and checks forall condition once only, instead of zipping all and then iterating over a second time to check the forall.

Answer (score 1):

As the number of cards is probably not that large, I would first try to use existing functionality as much as possible (this normally gives very short method bodies):

If the empty case does not matter:

```
def haveSameColor(cards: Seq[Card]) = 
  cards.tail.forall(cards.head.color == _.color)
```

If you want to handle the empty case differently, consider pattern matching:

```
def haveSameNumber(cards: Seq[Card], ifEmpty: Boolean = true) = {
  cards match {
    case Seq() =>
      ifEmpty

    case h +: t =>
      t.forall(h.number == _.number)
  }
}
```

As the number of cards is probably not that high, I would start with

```
def areAscending(cards: Seq[Card]) = {
  cards == cards.sortBy(c => (c.color, c.number))
}
```

If that turned out to be a hot spot, you could replace it by an optimized version later.

Generally speaking, I'd start with using functionality already provided by the standard library. 
Otherwise consider a `fold`/`reduce` or tail recursion.
Loops will not always be elegant, especially if you have to break out from it.

**Update**

As for `areAscending`, consider this version which uses tail-recursion:

```
def areAscendingWithTailRecursion(cards: List[Card], ifEmpty: Boolean = true) = {

  @tailrec
  def areAscendingWithTailRecursion(c: Card, remainder: List[Card]): Boolean = {
    remainder match {
      case Nil =>
        true

      case h :: t =>
        c.color <= h.color && c.number <= h.number && 
          areAscendingWithTailRecursion(h, t)
    }
  }

  cards match {
    case Nil =>
      ifEmpty

    case List(_) =>
      true

    case c :: remainder =>
      areAscendingWithTailRecursion(c, remainder)
  }
```

but I doubt if the effort is worth the gain in performance.

As for your use cases

- The first two functions translate literally into `forall` (universal quantifier). Probably hard to beat in terms of performance. And it's a single call to the collection library, so hard to beat in terms of conciseness as well.
- All functions should break out, if the result is known (no need to process the remaining part), so I would not use `fold`/`reduce`. In that case I prefer tail recursion.

Comment: How would you use `fold/reduce` to solve these problems?

Comment: @SebastianN. As for these problems, I would not (see update) :-) Do you need a function which requires to process *always* the complete list of cards?

Comment: @SebastianN. you can check my answer. I'd use takeWhile and not fold/reduce here (even though it's possible).

Comment: @Beryllium: quite on the contrary: I would prefer solutions which _don't_ need to traverse the whole sequence.

Comment: @SebastianN. Then, AFAIK, fold/reduce is not suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `takeWhile`, which is guaranteed to break early.

```
def haveSameColor(cards: Seq[Card]) =
  cards.takeWhile(_.color == cards.head.color) == cards.size

def haveSameNumber(cards: Seq[Card]) =
  cards.takeWhile(_.number == cards.head.number) == cards.size
```

Sorting cards and checking whether it's the same as current `cards` is O(n). If you need performance, you'd need to write a bit more verbose code - just iterate over `cards` and see if two elements are not in order (Scala *does* allow for non-local returns).

```
def areAscending(cards: Seq[Card])(implicit cardOrdering: Ordering[Card] = Ordering.fromLessThan(_.number < _.number)) =
  cards.sorted == cards
```

And here is the REPL:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_45). Type in expressions to have them evaluated. Type :help for more information.

scala> case class Card(number: Int, color: String) defined class Card

scala> val cards = Seq(
     |   Card(5, "red"),
     |   Card(7, "red"),
     |   Card(3, "black")
     | ) cards: Seq[Card] = List(Card(5,red), Card(7,red), Card(3,black))

scala> def haveSameColor(cards: Seq[Card]) = cards.takeWhile(_.color
== cards.head.color) == cards.size haveSameColor: (cards: Seq[Card])Boolean

scala> def haveSameNumber(cards: Seq[Card]) = cards.takeWhile(_.number
== cards.head.number) == cards.size haveSameNumber: (cards: Seq[Card])Boolean

scala> def areAscending(cards: Seq[Card])(implicit cardOrdering: Ordering[Card] = Ordering.fromLessThan(_.number < _.number)) =
     |     cards.sorted == cards areAscending: (cards: Seq[Card])(implicit cardOrdering: Ordering[Card])Boolean

scala> haveSameColor(cards) res0: Boolean = false

scala> haveSameNumber(cards) res1: Boolean = false

scala> areAscending(cards) res2: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been suggested to me on IRC:

(freely adapted)

```scala
def haveSameColor(cards: Seq[Card], ifEmpty: Boolean = true): Boolean = 
  if(cards.isEmpty) 
    ifEmpty
  else 
    cards.map(_.color).toSet.size == 1 

def haveSameNumber(cards: Seq[Card], ifEmpty: Boolean = true): Boolean =
  if(cards.isEmpty) 
    ifEmpty 
  else 
    cards.map(_.number).toSet.size == 1

def areAscending(cards: Seq[Card], ifEmpty: Boolean = true): Boolean = 
  if(cards.isEmpty)
    ifEmpty 
  else {
    val numbers = cards.map(_.number)
    numbers == numbers.sorted 
  }
```

While conceptually clear and very easy to read, I fear that these solutions are an overkill and not easy on resources / computation.

An alternative approach would fail **as soon** as it's clear that not all elements are equal, or the sequence is not ascending.

Additionally, I was hoping that folding can be employed somehow... but since the output is different than the input (sequence vs. boolean) I don't know how that would work.